# How to add Instagram "Like" button to images pulled in by tags using Instagram API

Tags: api, tags, instagram

To start I just want to let you know that i'm VERY new to this. I'm surprised I even got this far, but now i'm stuck. Currently this script will successfully pull in photo's with a specific tag.

I'm trying to do 2 additional things here. I need to figure out how to put the instagram LIKE button on the images, and I need to paginate the data so I can pull in more photo's (probably around 100 or so, I wouldn't mind if I have to add a "next page" button). I've read up as much as I could on this and other sites but have gotten nowhere due to my lack of knowledge (this is my first API script and first time working with PHP so the advanced lingo throws me off).

Can anyone explain this to me like I'm 5 years old? Or suggest an alternate route to take with this project or a link to somewhere I can learn how to do this (NOT the Instagram Developer site, i've already gone through it and KIND OF understand what they're saying, but my lack of coding knowledge outside of HTML and CSS is very limited)

```
<?php
// Supply a user id and an access token
$userid = "XXX";
$accessToken = "XXX";

// Gets our data
function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
    }

// Pulls and parses data.
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/exampletag/media/recent?access_token=XXX");
$result = json_decode($result);
?>


<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
    <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your pagination, have a look at this tutorial. It helped me, I think once you work through this, you will understand how to add your 'like' buttons as well.

http://eduvoyage.com/search-instagram-pagination.html

You will need to use the following POST to add a like to an image.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes

Refer to the Instagram API: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/

Comment: Tutorial is unavailable, domen is for sale.